# failure on union arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [cate_id] => 6
            [cate_name] => mobile
            [cate_parent] => 0
            [cate_order] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [cate_id] => 17
                            [cate_name] => old styled phone
                            [cate_parent] => 6
                            [cate_order] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [24] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cate_id] => 24
                                            [cate_name] => nokia1
                                            [cate_parent] => 17
                                            [cate_order] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [cate_id] => 18
                            [cate_name] => smart phone
                            [cate_parent] => 6
                            [cate_order] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [21] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cate_id] => 21
                                            [cate_name] => apple
                                            [cate_parent] => 18
                                            [cate_order] => 1
                                        )

                                    [23] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cate_id] => 23
                                            [cate_name] => nokia
                                            [cate_parent] => 18
                                            [cate_order] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [cate_id] => 20
                            [cate_name] => tablet
                            [cate_parent] => 6
                            [cate_order] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [cate_id] => 19
            [cate_name] => accessories
            [cate_parent] => 0
            [cate_order] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [cate_id] => 22
                            [cate_name] => phone case
                            [cate_parent] => 19
                            [cate_order] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I wrote a function which would get ids of specific category's children. For example, if I give "6", it will return 17,24,18,21,23,20. Here is my function:

```
function get_category_children($categories_tree, $parent)
    {
    //$children_list = '';
        $children_list = array();
        foreach ($categories_tree as $categories_branch)
        {
            if ($categories_branch['cate_parent'] == $parent)
            {
                $children_list[] = $categories_branch['cate_id'];
            }
            else 
            {
                //echo "{$categories_branch['cate_id']},";
            }

            if( ! empty($categories_branch['children']))
            {
                //echo "{$categories_branch['cate_id']},";
                $children_list += get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']);
            }

        }

        return $children_list;
    }
```

But it only return 17,18,20. At first I thought there is something wrong in my function's logic, but when I change $children_list's type from array to string, like this:

```
function get_category_children($categories_tree, $parent)
{
    $children_list = '';
    //$children_list = array();
    foreach ($categories_tree as $categories_branch)
    {
        if ($categories_branch['cate_parent'] == $parent)
        {
            $children_list .= $categories_branch['cate_id'].',';
        }
        else 
        {
            //echo "{$categories_branch['cate_id']},";
        }

        if( ! empty($categories_branch['children']))
        {
            //echo "{$categories_branch['cate_id']},";
            $children_list .= get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']);
        }

    }

    return $children_list;
}
```

It works fairy good and return everything I need, so I think may be there is something wrong with `$children_list += get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']);`, so new array didn't add to old array, but I don't know why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you write var_dump($children_list;) from second example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$children_list += get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']);` is your problem. You cannot `+=` to join arrays. Works great for incrementing integers, but not so great with arrays ;)

Instead, merge the arrays:

```
$children_list = array_merge( $children_list, 
get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']) );
```

Complete code:

```
function get_category_children($categories_tree, $parent)
    {
    //$children_list = '';
        $children_list = array();
        foreach ($categories_tree as $categories_branch)
        {
            if ($categories_branch['cate_parent'] == $parent)
            {
                $children_list[] = $categories_branch['cate_id'];
            }
            else 
            {
                //echo "{$categories_branch['cate_id']},";
            }

            if( ! empty($categories_branch['children']))
            {
                //echo "{$categories_branch['cate_id']},";
                // $children_list += get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']);

                $children_list = array_merge( $children_list, 
                get_category_children($categories_branch['children'], $categories_branch['cate_id']) );

            }

        }

        return $children_list;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I don't know who voted down your answer, but not me. I'm sorry that I can't vote up because of my little points.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getChildren($in_arr) {
  $out_arr = array();
  foreach( $in_arr['children'] as $key => $child ) {
    $out_arr[] = $key;
    if( isset($child['children'] ) {
      $out_arr = array_merge($out_arr, get_children($child));
    }
    return $out_arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this solves the problem instead of just supplying an answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can't merge arrays with `+` operator. You need [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I don't know who voted down your answer, but not me. I'm sorry that I can't vote up because of my little points.